SQS Messages Enter Visibility Timeout but Lambda did not Receive Them
I have a single concurrency Lambda that I want to trigger from SQS messages, I also have defined BatchSize to one so only one message is received by the Lambda. However, I can see that my SQS is sending more than one message as I can see from the Messages Sent metric and the worst thing is I have a function in my Lambda to delete certain messages in the queue however all the messages are unavailable and immediately enter the visibility timeout(Approximate number of messages not visible). So the Lambda when calling sqs to receive messages doesn't receive anything because the other messages are not visible to it for some reason.
What am I missing, why are the messages entering their visibility timeout when the Lambda did not receive them in the first place, why are they being shown as sent?
I expect my Lambda to receive one message at a time and be able to access and delete the other messages inside my queue.

The first thing to do is to add print(event) to the start of the Lambda function. This will make the event available in CloudWatch Logs so you can see exactly what the Lambda function is receiving. Then, you can determine whether it is receiving multiple records within the event. I recommend that you avoid using the SQS management console to retrieve messages and metrics because it can interfere with the flow of messages as it also retrieves messages and triggers visibility timeouts.
